# Transit time at Sabiha Gokcen

Tags: transit, turkey, short-connections

I am flying into Sabiha Gokcen on from Rome at 6:15PM and have a connecting flight to Antalya at 8:45PM that same evening.  I am not a Turkish citizen either.  Is 2.5 hours enough to get out of the aircraft, clear customs, collect bags, go to thhe Domestic terminal, and check-in for my flight to Antalya? Does the Flash Pass/Fastrack help speed any of this up for me?

Comment: Thank-you Daniil - yes I will need to collect my luggage as I have 2 different PNR numbers therefore 2 different tickets.  I am flying from Canada to Istanbul on Alitalia through Rome.  From Rome the flight is operated by Pegasus on a code share.  Although my flight from SAW to Antalya is also by Pegasus, it is a different PNR.  As such I'll have to clear customs in Istanbul and check-in again at the domestic terminal.  Is the domestic terminal in the same building as the international arrivals? Also, do I need a fast track pass for the domestic departure?

Answer (score 2):

The minimum transfer time expected should be 1 hours and 15/30 minutes for an international to a domestic flight.

> If you arrive on an International flight and continue on domestic flight (or vice versa), **the minimum time varies between 1h 15 min. and 1h 30 min**. The longer time needed for domestic/international transiting is due to passing through immigration, where queues are often long. There are some connections with domestic flights, where baggage needs to be rechecked.

([Source](http://www.connectionreview.com/blog/connecting-times-at-istanbul-ataturk-and-sabiha-gokcen-airports-27))

The fast track arrival pass offers a dedicated lane for passport control and is €25 online To be safe it would be recommended to get it but it is your decision.

[Link for more info](http://www.sabihagokcenfasttrack.com/product-details/fast-track-passport-control-on-arrival/).